# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un fnGetData() almacenado en un json mediante ajax a mi controlador?

Tags: laravel, ajax, datatables

Estoy trabajando con Laravel 5.8 en el cual estoy utilizando una datatable la cual relleno dinámicamente con jquery y la función row.add();

```
 var clase = $("#clase").val();
 var fecha_clase = $("#fecha_clase").val();
 var hora_clase = $("#hora_clase_input").val();
 var duracion_clase = $("#duracion_clase").val();
 var profesor = $("#profesor").val();
 var vehiculo = $('#vehiculo').val();
 var contador = parseFloat(table2.rows().count()) + 1;
 var btnEliminar = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger elevation-1 btn_eliminar">Quitar</button>';

table2.row.add( [
       contador,
       fecha_clase,
       hora_clase,
       duracion_clase,
       profesor,
       vehiculo,
       btnEliminar
   ] ).draw();
   table2.columns.adjust();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con la función fnGetData() de datatable capturo todos los datos en arrays y los transformo a json mediante JSON.stringify como lo muestro a continuación

```
var p = $("#tablaAgregados").dataTable().fnGetData();
var json = JSON.stringify(p);
```

el json que me genera es el siguiente

```
[
 [1,"16/11/2019","17:40","3","47","6","<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-outline-danger elevation-1 btn_eliminar\">Quitar</button>"]
 [2,"18/11/2019","20:40","5","48","5","<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-outline-danger elevation-1 btn_eliminar\">Quitar</button>"]
]
```

Intente enviarlo de esta forma y otras similares sin exitó

```
$.ajax({
   url : "{{ route('alumno.horario') }}",
   data : json,
   method : 'POST',
   success : function(response){
       alert("funciona bien");
   },
   error: function(error){
       alert("No funciona");
   }
});
```

Esta es mi ruta `Route::post('alumno/horario','alumnoController@storeHorario')->name('alumno.horario');`

En resumen, necesito enviar de alguna forma los datos agregados a la tabla a mi controlador, para posteriormente guardarlos en la base de datos.

---

***Actualización***

logre recibir el json en mi controlador (como lo muestra el dump() mas abajo)

pero ahora tengo el problema que al apretar el `#btnCrear` el ajax me indica error, aunque en el controlador este recibiendo correctamente el json.

```
$('body').on('click','#btnCrear', function sendData(){

      var p = $("#tablaAgregados").dataTable().fnGetData();

      $.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('alumno.horario') }}",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        contentType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(p),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success : function(response){
          Toast.fire({
            type: 'success',
            title: 'Su alumno ha sido registrado con éxito'
          });
        },
        error: function(error){
          Toast.fire({
            type: 'error',
            title: 'Ha ocurrido un problema con el registro de horario práctico'
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

función de mi controlador

```
public function storeHorario(Request $request)
   {
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent());
   }
```

resultado con `dump($data)`

[image: introducir el código aquí]

Comment: Qué error te aparece?

Comment: Logre solucionarlo, en mi controlador me faltaba devolver el json para que ajax lo reconozca como sucess

```return json_encode($data);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucion

agregar `return json_encode($data);` en el controlador